# Hatcher Chapter $0$ Exercise $7$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am going through Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf). But I'm stuck with the Exercise $7$ of chapter $0$ in page $18$.

> Fill in the details in the following construction from [Edwards 1999] of a compact space $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with the same properties as the space $Y$ in Exercise 6, that is, $Y$ is contractible but does not deformation retract to any point. To begin, let $X$ be the union of an infinite sequence of cones on the Cantor set arranged end-to-end,
>   as in the figure. Next, form the one-point compactification of $X \times \mathbb{R}$. This embeds in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a closed disk with curved ‘fins’ attached along circular arcs, and with the one-point compactification of $X$ as a cross-sectional slice.
>   The desired space $Y$ is then obtained from this subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by wrapping one more cone on the Cantor set around the boundary of the disk.

[image: figure]

I cannot understand the construction of the space $Y$. After the one-point compactification of $X \times{} \mathbb{R}$, how is this new space embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Also what does the last line mean?

> ...by wrapping one more cone on the Cantor set around the boundary of the disk.

Any help about this is appreciated. Can anyone at least provide me a link to the paper [Edwards 1999] mentioned in the question? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the problem statement in your question?

Comment: I've put the problem in.

Comment: By the way, there's is a bibliography at the end of the book. It says that [Edwards 1999] is "R. Edwards, A contractible, nowhere locally connected compactum, Abstracts A.M.S. 20 1999), 494." Unfortunately that paper doesn't seem to be on mathscinet, and I don't know where to find "Abstracts A.M.S.".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, thanks for the info. But I couldn't find a single reference to the paper cited in the bibliography (except maybe for its mention in the bibliography itself)!

Comment: Here is [a link to Abstracts of the AMS](https://www.ams.org/publications/journals/journalsframework/abs), but it seems that on-line versions only go back to 2009.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My instructor informed me that the paper in question is by Prof. Robert Edwards of UCLA. I contacted him over e-mail about his paper and he was kind enough to correspond. He informed me that : *..there is no published paper, only his abstract in the AMS Abstracts of the May 1999 AMS meeting in Denton TX.*

He also mentioned that there is a clarification needed in the question : *..all of the cones-on-Cantor-sets of the space $X$ are of the same size. So its "baseline" is meant to be $[0,\infty)$, not $[0,1]$.*

So now, I can visualize the space $X\times{}\mathbb{R}$ as the upper half plane with 'fins' attached. The one-point compactification, say $C$, is then embedded as a closed disc in $R^3$ with fins attached. This disc has the one-point compactification of the $X$-axis as its boundary. As for its cross-section, we have the one-point compactification of $X$, as shown in the picture. Another cone-on-Cantor-set is wrapped around the boundary to obtain the space $Y$.

The space $Y$ is contractible, since we can retract each of the fins and obtain the closed disc $D^2$, which is contractible.

But $Y$ does not deformation retract to a point. Any neighborhood of a point in $Y$ has infinitely many disjoint fins and thus it is not path connected. For points on the boundary of $C$, the extra cone-on-Cantor-set provides the disjoint fins in its neighborhood. Then by problem **0.5** of Hatcher's book, $Y$ does not deformation retract to a point.