# Example of a compact space in $\mathbb R^3$ which is contractible but doesn't deformation retract to any point

Tags: general-topology

**Update:**

I think of a way that $Y$ can defromation retract to $D^2$ in the weak sence, so from Exercise $0.4$, $Y$ is contractible. See tha answer below.

---

This is Exercise $7$ of chapter $0$ in page $18$ of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

The following explanation is from Hatcher himself:

> $X$ is union of an infinite sequence of cones on the Cantor set arranged end-to-end, and $[0,1)$ is the "baseline". Y is one-point compactification of $X \times \mathbb R$, which is obtained by adding the endpoint $1$ of the interval $[0,1)$.

**My question:**

Why is $Y$ contractible?

This question was asked before: [Hatcher Chapter $0$ Exercise $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943772/) 
, but the answer might contain some mistake. It says *"The space $Y$ is contractible, since we can retract each of the fins and obtain the closed disc $D^2$, which is contractible."*

Some clarification: The picture in Hatcher's book is equivalent to the original construction from Edwards, which is stated in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989872/557551).

But **only** retraction doesn't preserve the homotopy type, retracting each of the fins is not deformation retraction since it's **not** continuous, and $Y$ **doesn't** deformation retract to $D^2$.

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: You can stick the word "deformation" in front of "retract", to make that sentence more clear: *The space $Y$ is contractible, since we can* **deformation** *retract each of the fins...*

Comment: @LeeMosher That's not a true deformation retraction actually, just a deformation retraction **in the weak sence**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$X$ is union of infinite sequence of cones on the Cantor set arranged end-to-end and getting smaller and smaller. The ''baseline'' of $X$ is $[0,1)$. One-point compactification of $X \times \mathbb R$ is obtained by adding the endpoint $1$ of $[0,1)$.

After one-point compactification, $\{0\}\times \mathbb R$ together with the additional point $\{1\}\times \{0\}$ becomes the boundary of $D^2$.

$Y$ is obtained from one-point compactification of $X \times \mathbb R$ by wrapping one more cone on the Cantor set around the boundary of $D^2$.

$Y$ doesn't deformation retract to a point, since any neighborhood of a point in $Y$ is disconnected.

$X$ can deformation retract to baseline $[0,1)$ in the weak sense in the following way:

For $n \in \mathbb N$, the point on baseline $[1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}, 1-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}]$ moves to $[1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}, 1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}]$ alone $[0,1)$, and the point on $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$ moves to $\{0\}$.

The point on cones moves to $[0,1)$ in the similar way, so $X$ deformation retract to baseline $[0,1)$ in the weak sense, and one-point compactification of $X \times \mathbb R$ deformation retract to $D^2$ in the weak sense.

$Y$ deformation retract to $D^2$ with a cone on the Cantor set around the boundary of $D^2$ in the weak sense.

This space can deformation retract to $D^2$ in the weak sense by moving points on cone and rotating $D^2$ clockwise.

Thus $D^2 \hookrightarrow Y$ is homotopy equivalence, $D^2$ is contractible, so $Y$ is contractible.